# internal and external address bus

Tags: architecture, assembly, microprocessors

Based on my knowledge,i know there is external and internal data bus,but i wonder if there is internal and external address bus as i saw a diagram showing intel 8088 microprocessor with this two thing mention,anybody mind explain the two of it??thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The 8088 internal address bus was a 20-bit bus.  The interface to external chips was via 20 pins, of which 8 are shared with the external data bus.  The `ALE` (`Address Latch Enable`) signal is used by off-chip hardware to latch the 20-bit address while it is present on the pins.